# cakephp changes when changing the name of the database table

Tags: cakephp

I work in cakephp, I have a database table named  'movements' I want the named 'movements_bags' what changes need to be made​​:
- The model
-the controller
-folder view

Answer (score 1):

To use a table with a name that is outside the [CakePHP table naming convention](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP/CakePHP-Conventions.html) (e.g. `Movement` model has table names `movements`, but you want to use the table named `movements_bags`) you simply specify which table name to use in your model with the `$useTable` property:

```
class Movement extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = 'movements_bags'; // default would be movements
    // ...
}
```

Comment: is what I can 2 or 3 different models use the same database table, for example **I have a table named movements and two models named Movement and Blocks**
`class Movement extends AppModel {
     var $ useTable = 'movements'; 
     / / ...
}`
`class Block extends AppModel {
     var $ useTable = 'movements';
     / / ...
}`

Comment: I don't see why not... although it seems pretty strange to do that

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Scrowler answer, but if you are not happy with this answer you can try bellow code.

change controller name to MovementsBagsController.

And change controller class name

```
class MovementsBagsController extends AppController {
}
```

Change your model name to MovementsBag

and change model class name

```
class MovementsBag extends AppModel {

 }
```

change view folder to `MovementsBags`

I think that will work fine now.

Comment: please Select this answer if it's solve your problem.